# Norm of a linear operator on C[-1,1]

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I am an undergraduate student of functional analysis. I am trying to find the norms of the following linear (integral) operators:

Let $A:C[0,1]\to C[0,1]$ defined as

1. $$Ax(t)=\int_0^1 x(s)\sin [\pi(t-s)]ds$$
2. $$Ax(t)=\int_0^1 x(s) \mathrm{e}^{(t-s)}ds$$
   Here $C[0,1]$ is the space of continuous real-valued functions defined on $[0,1]$ with the usual supremum norm. I need to find $\|A\|$ for both of the operators. I have shown that they are bounded linear operators. I do not know how to derive $\|A\|$ from onwards.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you give any upper bounds for the respective operators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. \begin{eqnarray}
   |A(x(t))|&&\leq \|x\|_{\infty}\int_{0}^1|\sin \pi(t-s)|ds
   \end{eqnarray}
   After transformation $s-t=u$ we have
   \begin{eqnarray}
   |A(x(t))|&&\leq \|x\|_{\infty}\int_{0}^1|\sin \pi(t-s)|ds\\
   &&=\|x\|_{\infty}\int_{t}^{1-t}|\sin \pi u|du. 
   \end{eqnarray}
   So, $\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|A(x(t))|\leq \|x\|_{\infty} \int_0^1 \sin \pi u\ du=\frac{2}{\pi}\|x\|_{\infty}$. Therefore, $\|A\|\leq\frac{2}{\pi}$. Putting $x(t)=1$ and after some calculation we get $\|A\|=\frac{2}{\pi}$.
2. \begin{eqnarray}
   |A(x(t))|&&\leq \|x\|_{\infty}\int_{0}^1 e^{(t-s)}ds\\
   && =\|x\|_{\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{e}\right)e^t\\
   \end{eqnarray}
   So, $\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|A(x(t))|\leq \|x\|_{\infty}(e-1)$. Therefore, $\|A\|\leq (e-1)$. Again, put $x(t)=1$, i.e., $\|x\|_{\infty}=1$. Then $$\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|A(x(t))|=e-1.$$ Hence $\|A\|=e-1$.